# getting an erro when trying invoke a generic function parameter, swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

My function is taking a generic type parameter which conforms to a certain of protocol

```
    // This is my function
    func instantiateViewController<T: ViewControllerIdentifier>(viewController: UIViewController) -> T
    {
        let controller  =   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewController.identifier) as! T
        return controller
    }

    // This is an extension of my protocol
    extension ViewControllerIdentifier where Self: UIViewController
    {
        var identifier: String
        {
            return String(self)
        }
     }
```

At another class, I am instantiating a view controller by invoking above function like following:

```
let editAssignmentViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(MyTestClass)
```

However, xcode is giving me an error like below

```
 Cannot convert value of type '(MyTestClass).Type' (aka 'MyTestClass') to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
```

Does anyone know what I am missing and how to fix this error

Comment: You've defined `instantiateViewController` to take a parameter of an instance of a `UIViewController`, and you're passing it a type, not an instance. That's why you're getting the error that you are.

Comment: @rob: my goal is when passing MyTestClass into the `instantiateViewController` method, I'm expecting the return will be `MyTestClass` view controller.

Comment: @rob:right now I am passing the type to my method. Is a way to change the parameter to a type instead of UIViewController ?

Comment: can you explain what is the meaning of T.Type. I am trying T.dynamicType but it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118494/discussion-between-tonytran-and-rob).

Answer (score 2):

I'm gathering that your intent is that you want to be able to do something like:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(SomeViewController)
```

If that's what you want to do, it seems that it can be accomplished without any protocol, with simply:

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    func instantiateViewController<T: UIViewController>(viewController: T.Type) -> T {
        return instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(T)) as! T
    }
}
```

I must confess that I'd prefer to stick with the standard

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeViewController") as! SomeViewController
```

Comment: the standard is using "SomeViewController". I want to avoid it by using exact name of the view controller. Therefore, you can avoid the typo.